# Error creating a new SQL Server 2017 maintenance plan

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm getting error CO_E_CLASSSTRING ("Invalid class string") while trying to create a new maintenance plan in Microsoft Sql Server Management 18.0

I already tried to reinstall all the components of SQL Server 17 but it didn't help.

[image: Sql server management 18]

This is the error details :

> ===================================
>
> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (mscorlib)
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DatabaseMaintenance.MaintDesignerMenuHandler.GetExistingPackageNames(ServerConnection
>   serverConnection)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DatabaseMaintenance.MaintDesignerMenuHandler.GetNewPackageName(ServerConnection
>   serverConnection)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DatabaseMaintenance.MaintDesignerMenuHandler.Invoke()
>
> ===================================
>   Incorrect Class String (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401F3
>   (CO_E_CLASSSTRING)) (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap)
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.GetPackageInfos(String
>   strFolder, String serverName, String serverUserName, String
>   serverPassword)
>
> ===================================
>
> Incorrect Class String (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401F3
>   (CO_E_CLASSSTRING)) (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap)
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.ApplicationClass.GetPackageInfos(String
>   bstrPackageFolder, String bstrServerName, String bstrServerUserName,
>   String bstrServerPassword)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.GetPackageInfos(String
>   strFolder, String serverName, String serverUserName, String
>   serverPassword)

Comment: [Pictures of exceptions are not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) also [Research is an important first step in solving problems](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/). Also include the translated error message or try to get the original error message in English as this is an English site. Leaving it in (not sure what language that is) means most users will not be able to help you.

Comment: Could you 'copy message' and paste the message into the question too? (e.g. formatted as a quote or code block if necessary). I doubt it, but is there any more information in 'Show details'?

Comment: Show pertinent code to avoid having the question closed as off topic

Comment: @Rup i added the error details into the question

Comment: @Igor didn't notice that the error message was in French, i added the original error message in English

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same error & fixed it by just connecting to the server from my laptop instead of locally through SSMS and creating the maintenance plan there.  I haven't tested the long term fix yet but it might be to uninstall & reinstall SSMS on the SQL server itself.

Possible root cause is that this was a new installation of SQL server 2017 on an old server that had several other versions previously installed.  I deleted all the old versions but left the existing SSMS installation on the server and that's when I started having this error.